# Can't see how $e^{\operatorname{Log}(z)} = z$ in these notes

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following statements written down in my notes. But I can't see what is happening to get from the second last line to the last line.

$$e^{\operatorname{Log}(z)} = e^{\log(|z|) + i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}
= e^{\log(|z|)}[\cos(\operatorname{Arg}(z)) + i\sin(\operatorname{Arg}(z)]
= z$$

Anyone know how the second last line is able to reduce into just $z$ on the final line?

Comment: it's from the initial $e^{\log(z)}$ I think

Comment: What is $Re[z]$ and $Im[z]$ in terms of $|z|$ and the angle $z$ makes with the positive real axis? It's just polar coordinates, basically.

Answer (score 2):

suppose $z=re^{i\theta}$,then $e^{log(|z|)}=r$,$[Cos(Arg(z)) + iSin(Arg(z)]=e^{i\theta}$,

so $e^{log(|z|)}[Cos(Arg(z)) + iSin(Arg(z)]=z$.